# How do I know when the village ends in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I don’t know how to find the edge of a village. I need to know to know how far to put my iron farm, but I want it as close to the village as can be, so I don’t have to walk far(the village is my home) I play mcpe, the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

> The borders are 32 blocks (two chunks) from the village center, or 32 blocks from any village point of interest (a point of interest is any bed, bell, or job site block). The village center is typically the northwest corner of the village bell or one of the claimed beds.
>
> -Minecraft Wiki

In other words, find the bell and count 2 chunks (32 blocks) in all 4 directions and go about another 15 blocks so your iron farm can work properly.